# How do I reactivate a path?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If I have selected another layer and a path is incomplete, so it just looks like a path, how do I "re-activate" it so I can continue to add anchor points?

Also, can a path only be manipulated (e.g. Rotated) once it has first been converted to a selection?

Lastly, if I have made multiple paths on the same layer, how does one select/edit just one of them?

Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**question 1:**

if you have a path that is not complete and you have clicked off of the path. you can resume simply by getting your pen tool and hovering directly over the anchor point where the path ends a small box with a line through it should apear to the bottom right of your curser. once you see this icon click and continue working with the path.

**question 2:**

no, a path can be rotated or transformed before it is converted to a selection. simply select the path with the path selection tool(A) and go to edit > free transform path... or use the key command ctrl + T or cmd + T for mac.

**question 3:**

if you have made multiple paths on the same layer you have use the direct selection tool(A) (if you do not see the direct selection tool click and hold the path selection tool until the submenu pops up and select it) once you have the tool selected you can click and drag a marque(box selection) around the path you want or click directly on the anchor point you want. Holding shift allows  you to add more anchor points to your current selection.